Short-stay Schengen Visa for Germany: Which purpose?
Just want to ask for a question re: declaring a purpose for my Schengen visa application for Germany. As I understand, all purposes fall under "short-stay" visa. I have a letter of invitation from a sports team asking me to go to their fan club event. The event consists of museum tours, dinner/lunches with the team's fan club director, and watching a live game. I'll be paying for myself: flights, accommodation.
For this one, can I put "business" as a purpose? The sports team is not related at all to my current  company where I work. Also, I plan on asking for a 9-day visa validity— the event is for four days but I plan on spending the remaining days hopefully for tourism  as well. In this case, can I also include "tourism" as a purpose? Won't it present a conflict if so? Or is the "other" option also available, that being "attending a fan club event" and just explain everything in the cover letter?
Any suggestions or advice would highly be appreciated! Thank you so much!

What line of reasoning leads you from "fan club" to "business"?

@phoog: IMHO: a private corporation that invite a person may seem business related (and in fact the hidden intention is about that: publicity to get more incomes)

@GiacomoCatenazzi how is this different from Disneyland Paris or indeed any hotel seeking clients from abroad?  That doesn't make the clients into business visitors.  If you're a business visitor it will generally be because the trip is furthering your business interests, not because you are patronizing businesses in the place you're visiting.

@phoog: no need to justify. I agree, just I see that people may be unsure. And it is not Disneyland: it is a private event, invitation-only.

@GiacomoCatenazzi thank you for your insights; both are very valid points! I included the "business" purpose on the basis that I'll be submitting an invitation letter from a sports organization who'll organize events and other activities. I come from a country where visa rejections are pretty common (weak passports), and since I'm a first-time applicant, I want to make sure I'm doing the right things and being consistent in my application and in the requirements sent. I probably might end up choosing "other" and stating "attending a fan event," then choose "tourism" as my secondary purpose

@MUNAkid attending a fan event is tourism, you being invited to it does not change anything, you should just choose it as your primary purpose. No need to confuse visa officials.

I interpret it as tourism: it is visiting things. it is not unlike concerts, with a VIP ticket (so visiting close to normal public things and talk with insiders).
And the invitation letter would make clear the intention, so if you were wrong, you were not misleading act.
Just the German officers may envy you, but that should not matter.

You say that this fan club event is not related to your employment, and you do not say anything suggesting that you have other business activities relating to fan clubs.  Unless there is something else that you forgot to mention, you certainly should not choose "business."
(It's perfectly permissible to mix business and tourism on the same trip; there's no conflict in choosing both, if for example you are meeting a client and then spending a week on the beach.)
Tourism is not restricted to visiting sites of interest or traveling around with your eyes on the horizon.  For visa applications, it is typically interpreted so broadly that any trip for personal interest can be considered tourism.  If I were you I'd just choose tourism and leave it at that.
If you are worried for some particular reason that the fan club activities would not be considered tourism, please edit the question to explain.

Anecdotally, I've been told (by an equivalent of tls/vfs, on the topic of schengen visas thru Germany) to only pick business if I'm being paid for the trip by my employer.

Thank you Ave. This information is very helpful!
